# Passing ArrayList from jsp to servlet on form submit

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am trying to pass arraylist object from a jsp page on submitting a form to a servlet.

Code of jsp page :-

```
<form action="NewServlet">
<%
    ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
    al.add("abc");
    al.add("xyz");
    request.setAttribute("allproducts", al);
%>
<input type="submit" value="Show"></form>
```

Code of NewServlet :-

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     
ServletException, IOException {
ArrayList al=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("allproducts");
System.out.print(al.get(0));
}
```

When I run this code , I am getting `NullPointerException` at line "System.out.print(al.get(0))".

Can anyone tell me why is it happening?

Also what should I do if I want to use this al object in servlet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because

```
request.getAttribute("allproducts");
```

**returns `null`**

And you are calling a method `al.get(0)` on `null` object.

---

#### Why did you get `al`  `null`?

When you submit the form **new request** is submitted resulting in flush of your old `request` object. New `request` object does not contain the array list which you had set on JSP.

---

#### Oracle docs for `NullPointerException`

```
public class NullPointerException
             extends RuntimeException
```

Thrown when an application attempts to use `null` in a case where an object is required. These include:

> - Calling the instance method of a null object.
> - **Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.**
> - Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
> - Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
> - Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

---

#### Side Note

- Do not write scriptlets in JSP, because scriptlets shouldn't be used in JSPs for more than a decade. Learn the JSP [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info), the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info), and use servlet for the Java code. [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)

Comment: I want to use the araylist of jsp in servlet.Can you tell me how can I do so ?

Comment: @user3471460 : Iterate array list and create `hidden` fields. Give same name to each hidden field. In servlet access hidden fields with `request.getParameterVales("hidden_name");`, it returns you array. From array you can create array list in servlet. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.hidden.html http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/hidden